# Need assistance with adding a footer to an Android ListView such that it does not overlap the entries of the ListView

Tags: java, android, xml

The code below is for a ListView with a footer, the problem I am facing is that the lower entries in the ListView are getting overlapped by the footer.
 So Could you suggest any solution (because I tried a lot and it each situation I am getting the same overlapping result) or some other way to do it. Thanks in advance. I have also posted the code of the footer just in case.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/homeParentLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/listV_main"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <include android:id="@+id/footer" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/mymenu" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </include>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code for mymenu.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_gravity="bottom">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text=" "
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/imgSetting" 
                android:src="@drawable/settings_gear_icon_256"
                android:layout_width="60dip"
                android:layout_height="60dip" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                android:clickable="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text=" "
                android:gravity="center"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text=" "
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/imgLogin" 
                android:layout_width="60dip"
                android:src="@drawable/login_lock_256" 
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_height="60dip" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text=" "
                android:gravity="center"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text=" "
                android:gravity="center"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is the problem that the bottom of your scrollview ends at the bottom of the footer instead of at the top of the footer? i.e. do you want the scrollview to exist in a frame whose bottom is the top of the footer?

Comment: Yes, my problem is that the bottom of my listview ends at the bottom of the footer instead of at the top of the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a relative layout like this:
Declare the relative layout, then declare the footer as the first element.
These properties are the important ones for the footer:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:id="@+id/footer_id"
```

Then declare your listView with this property:

```
android:layout_above="@id/footer_id"
```

And that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Although a `RelativeLayout` generally gives you more flexibility for layout design, in the case of a fairly straightforward layout like this, you can use weights to distribute the screen estate in a similar manner using a `LinearLayout`.

Note that the most notable changes below are in the `ListView` declaration. The height of '0dp' and the weight of '1' will make the `ListView` take up as many space (vertically) as possible, without pushing the footer off the bottom. Effectively, this will bottom-align the footer.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/homeParentLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/listV_main"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />

    <include android:id="@+id/footer" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/mymenu" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I also took the liberty of removing what appeared to be some left-over tags/attributes from playing around with a `RelativeLayout`.